# Bash Script to Check Directory Structure?

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I'm trying to write a bash script to check whether the right files are in a directory, and whether within that directory they are nested properly.

I know how to check if certain files are present, and how to traverse down directories, but how do I check the relations of the files to each other!

Comment: Please define "check the relations of the files to each other".  The only relation at the file system level is the fact they are in the same directory.  Then show us the code of what you have done up to now.

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do is simple but grueling; just run the following before your main script:

```
[ -e /path/to/file1 ] && echo File1 exists || echo File1 missing
```

or for multiple files:

```
if [ -e /path/to/file1 ] && [ -e /path/to/file2 ]
then
    echo "All files exist, directory intact"
else
    echo "One or more files are missing"
```

with `file1` and `file2` being the files you're looking for. Note that the `-e` option counts directories, so you can use this option for your entire directory structure.